# Every point of closed interval is an accumulation point in usual topology

Tags: general-topology

In book General Topology by Kelley it is stated:

Let $X$ be a set of real numbers with the usual topology. Let $A$ be open interval $(0,1)$.
Then *every point* of closed interval $[0,1]$ is an accumulation point of $A$.

I understand that $0$ and $1$ are accumulation points of A, because we can construct sequence in $A$ which converges to either point. But how is every point of $[0,1]$ an accumulation point of $A$?
 Surely $\frac12\in[0,1]$, so how is it an accumulation point of $A$?

Comment: $\frac1  2+\frac 1  n \to \frac 1  2$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy that's new revelation to me. I was under impression that accumulation points are only 'end-points' of closed interval, because every neighborhood of them intersects  the interval and complement of the interval.

Comment: You are getting confused between  boundary points and accumulation points.

Comment: @Kavi Indeed. Thank you.